# Is there a way to bring attention to a question I asked?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked a question a few weeks ago that was closed. It reopened recently due to continous editing, but since it is no longer new, I can't seem to get responses from the community. Is there a hypothetical way to raise awareness about it?

Comment: Link the question please.  I will help you out.

Answer (score 4):

Any edit or answer will show it as *fresh* again.  This isn't like a common forum — posts are curated and older posts are still interesting.  You don’t need “momentum” and “trendiness”.

In a fitting coincedence, I just got a gold “Great Answer” badge for a post made *over a year ago* (on a different SE).  It was posted in January of last year, last edited in September.

Answer (score 3):

Since your reputation is over 75, the right course of action is to [set a bounty](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).
With a bounty, you pay some amount of your rep (at least 50) to make your question both more visible and attractive.

Of course, a bounty can be seen as quite costly but if your question is good, you have all chances of getting it back from upvotes pretty soon.

Also, if you give us a link to your question here or on the chat, you have good chances of getting an answer that would bounce up your question on top of the active list.

Comment: This is correct.  Though I will mention that dropping 2/3 of your rep on a bounty is intimidating.  This is good community service for higher rep users ;)